# Pass GraphQL Header from request to subsequent Axios Request

Tags: axios, graphql, nestjs-graphql

I have an Angular application which is using Apollo Client for querying a GraphQL Server from a NestJS application. This NestJS application is executing a request through Axios to an external Backend.

How could be passed the client header set in all the GraphQL requests to the backend request through Axios?

Apollo Client GraphQL Request > NestJS Apollo Server GraphQL Resolver > Axios HTTP Request.

```
// Configure the Apollo Client with custom Authorization header
function createApollo() {
  const { api } = AngularConfigService.getConfig();

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')}`,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    link: authLink.concat(
      new HttpLink({ uri: `${api?.host}:${api?.port}/graphql` }),
    ),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false }),
    defaultOptions: {
      // more content here ...
    } as DefaultOptions,
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    Apollo,
    { provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS, useFactory: createApollo, },
  ]
})
```

In the Angular application service I request from GraphQL server as following:

```
getUsers(args: GraphQL.QueryUsersArgs) {
   return this.graphQLDataService.query<GraphQL.UserDto[]>(usersQuery, args); // where usersQuery contains the GraphQL users query
}
```

I connect the request from the GraphQL Server to Axios through the following service method in the NestJS server:

```
getAllUsers(
  args: UsersArgsDto,
): Observable<DataResponse<UserDto[]>> {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();

  this.getQueryFilterParams<UsersQueryFilterInput>(
    queryParams,
    args.queryFilters,
  );
  this.getPaginationParams(queryParams, args.pagination);
  this.getSortingParams(queryParams, args.sort);

  return this.httpService
    .get('/users', {
      ...this.globalConfig,
      params: queryParams,
    })
    .pipe(
      map((data) => data.data),
      validateObject(DataResponse<UsersDto[]>),
      catchError((err) => {
        throw err;
      }),
    );
}
```

I have access to the GraphQL request header through the context in the query or mutation, but I have not access in the Axios HTTP request linked to that.

Would be possible to pass to the HTTP context?

Comment: The client bit is irrelevant. The key is how you "connect the request from the GraphQL server to Axios" - that's done in a resolver presumably. Can you share that code? It needs to pass the context on to the service method.

Comment: Yes, I´m passing the context header through the resolver query or mutation, but I was thinking in something like an interceptor to avoid passing for each query or mutation to pass the specific header, and doing it in a more generic way. I will complete the code with the resolver query as soon I have access to the code.

Comment: Well your `context` function can generically (for each request) bundle up all the request headers so that they are available to any resolver. That's like *an interceptor* in that it runs before any resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using the following service:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class GraphQLContextService {
  constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) context: GraphQLCustomExecutionContext) {}

  getContextRequestHeaders() {
    return this.context.req.headers;
  }
}
```

Then I can use in the required service:

```
constructor(private readonly gqlContextService: GraphQLContextService)

getAllUsers(
  args: UsersArgsDto,
): Observable<DataResponse<UserDto[]>> {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();

  this.getQueryFilterParams<UsersQueryFilterInput>(
    queryParams,
    args.queryFilters,
  );
  this.getPaginationParams(queryParams, args.pagination);
  this.getSortingParams(queryParams, args.sort);

  return this.httpService
    .get('/users', {
      ...this.globalConfig,
      params: queryParams,
      // Here we can link the GraphQL Headers to the Axios request
      headers: this.gqlContextService.getContextRequestHeaders(); 
    })
    .pipe(
      map((data) => data.data),
      validateObject(DataResponse<UsersDto[]>),
      catchError((err) => {
        throw err;
      }),
    );
}
```